# Problem with table JOIN in MySQL and aggregation

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have three tables. This query will write down the right answer (x-lines for btv.id_user with appropriate btv.cas and race.id_zavod

```
SELECT `btv.id_user`, `btv.id_zavod`,`btv.cas`
FROM `btv`
JOIN `btu` ON `btv.id_user` = `btu.id_user`
JOIN `race` ON 'btv.id_zavod' = `race.id_zavod`
WHERE `race.type` = '8' AND `btv.id_user` = '607'
```

Result:

```
| 607 |  512 | 03:15:58 |  
| 607 |  730 | 03:01:18 |  
| 607 |  164 | 03:07:26 |  
| 607 |  767 | 02:58:31 |  
| 607 | 1147 | 03:06:47 |  
| 607 | 1149 | 03:09:41 |  
| 607 | 1178 | 03:24:20 |
```

But when I try to aggregate it to one row by the id_user it return correct min btv.cas but wrong join wrong race.id_zavod

```
SELECT `btv.id_user`, `btv.id_zavod`, MIN( `btv.cas` )
FROM `btv`
JOIN `btu` ON `btv.id_user` = `btu.id_user`
JOIN `race` ON 'btv.id_zavod' = `race.id_zavod`
WHERE `race.type` = '8' AND `btv.id_user` = '607'
GROUP BY `btv.id_user`
```

Result:

```
| 607 | 512 | 02:58:31 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use GROUP BY, the columns in the select-list must satisfy one of the following:

- Column is named in the GROUP BY (e.g. `btv.id_user` in your example)
- Column is inside an aggregate function (e.g. `MIN( btv.cas )` )
- Column is a *functional dependency* of the column(s) you named in the GROUP BY.

This is the error in your query:  `btv.id_zavod` has many values for each value of `btv.id_user`.  This does not satisfy functional dependency.  There must be only one value in `id_zavod` for each value of `id_user` for it to be a functional dependency.

In some database brands, this query would actually give you an error. MySQL is more flexible, trusting you to name only columns in the select-list that are functional dependencies of the column(s) you named in the GROUP BY.

Here's a query that returns what you want, the MIN value of `btv.cas` per `id_user`, with the corresponding value of `btv.id_zavod`:

```
SELECT b1.id_user, b1.id_zavod, b1.cas
FROM btv AS b1
 JOIN btu ON (b1.id_user = btu.id_user)
 JOIN race ON (b1.id_zavod = race.id_zavod)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN btv AS b2 ON (b1.id_user = bt2.id_user AND 
   (b1.cas > b2.cas OR (b1.cas = b2.cas AND b1.primarykey > b2.primarykey))
WHERE race.type = '8' AND b1.id_user = '607'
 AND b2.id_user IS NULL;
```

In other words, you need to do your join as before, but then join that to `btv` again, to see if there's another row with the same `id_user` value and a smaller value in `cas`.  Use an OUTER JOIN, because you're looking for the case where there is no match.  You can test for that with `b2.id_user IS NULL`, because OUTER JOIN makes all columns NULL when there is no match.

Note that there could be ties, so we add the extra term using the primary key as the tiebreaker.

You don't need to use GROUP BY in this query.  That's taken care of implicitly, because there will be only one row that satisfies the OUTER JOIN condition.

Answer (score 1):

The query you have written:

```
SELECT `btv.id_user`, `btv.id_zavod`, MIN( `btv.cas` )
FROM `btv`
JOIN `btu` ON `btv.id_user` = `btu.id_user`
JOIN `race` ON 'btv.id_zavod' = `race.id_zavod`
WHERE `race.type` = '8' AND `btv.id_user` = '607'
GROUP BY `btv.id_user`
```

won't run.  You need a group by id_zavod or something.  Can you tell us what query you are really running?  And what result set you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT `btv.id_user`, `btv.id_zavod`, MIN( `btv.cas` )
FROM `btv`
Inner JOIN `btu` ON `btv.id_user` = `btu.id_user`
Inner JOIN `race` ON 'btv.id_zavod' = `race.id_zavod`
WHERE `btv.id_user` = '607'
GROUP BY `btv.id_user` having `race.type` = '8'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but are you maybe looking for the [GROUP_CONCAT function?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply trying to fetch the lowest btv.cas value and its other corresponding columns? If so, you could just order by btv.cas and limit to 1 hit:

```
SELECT `btv.id_user`, `btv.id_zavod`,`btv.cas`
FROM `btv`
JOIN `btu` ON `btv.id_user` = `btu.id_user`
JOIN `race` ON 'btv.id_zavod' = `race.id_zavod`
WHERE `race.type` = '8' AND `btv.id_user` = '607'
ORDER BY `btv.cas` LIMIT 1
```

Comment: that's right, this will work for this SELECT, but later I want to use this select for all users (find minimal cas and correspondig id_zavod for all users)